# Select by Attributes not selecting ALL larger numbers greater than 75000 in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, select-by-attribute

I was trying to select all values over 75000 in Select by Attributes.

Surely I thought doing so would do just that, but it's essentially selecting only values that **begin with** 75 and 8 and 9 (even includes a low value like 900) and leaving out values like 100000, 200000, and 700000. I entered this:

```
SDE_DATE.DBO.Parcels.Total_AV > '75000'
```

Do you know how I can select all values greater than 75,000?

Comment: Get rid of the quotes.

Comment: Unfortunately this message pops up if I do that: There was an error with the expression. An invalid SQL statement was used. ...Might be how my system is set up, but it's not very lenient.

Comment: Thanks Fezter...I just had to convert field to Numeric, and now I can select without quotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select By Attribute is working fine, but your values are actually stored as text, not as numbers. Therefore, they are being sorted alphabetically instead of numerically, and your greater-than operation is also sorting alphabetically. You will need to either add a new **numeric** field and populate it with the values in your existing `Total_AV`field (if there are any text values in that field and you want to keep them), or convert that field to a numeric type.

Answer (score 3):

You should not put 75000 in quotes.

```
SDE_DATE.DBO.Parcels.Total_AV > 75000
```

Comment: Unfortunately this message pops up if I do that: There was an error with the expression.
An invalid SQL statement was used. ...Might be how my system is set up, but it's not very lenient.

Comment: Your field is string, convert it to nimeric

Comment: Might be characters in the field?

Comment: Yep, converting to numeric did the trick...thanks! Thanks for your help, FelixIP and Hydrographer!